# iPhoneアプリがApp Storeで公開されるURL について

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

はじめてiPhoneのアプリを作り、iTunes Connectで申請中です。
当面日本語のアプリを配布するのですが、数ヶ月後に英語版を作る予定です。
そこで、主言語を英語にして日本語をローカライズして申請を出しています。

今レヴュー待ちなのですが、「App Storeで表示」のところが
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/アプリ名/アプリid?l=ja&ls=1&mt=8
となっています。

1. このままこのURLがアプリ公開されたときのURLになるのでしょうか？
2. 今はまだ申請中ですので、URLをクリックすると、

> The item you've requested is not currently available in the U.S. store.

と出てくるのですが、公開される際　US ストアへ飛ぶようになるのでしょうか？

3. その際、日本語でローカライゼーションした説明文等は日本ではきちんと表示されるのでしょうか？

すみません、初めてなのでわからないことだらけです。できれば審査が通る前にURLの配布をしたいのです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1と2に対しての回答ですが、仰るとおりです。

```
iTunes Connect > マイ App > [アプリ名] > その他 > App Storeでの表示
```

上記のリンクがアプリ公開URLになりますので、こちらのURLを先方にお伝えください。
設定した公開日(指定した日の各国において午前12時)を過ぎると閲覧可能になります。

3に対しての回答ですが、以下のURLのカッコの箇所をjpに変更すると、日本語で設定した説明文やスクリーンショットが表示されます。

```
https://itunes.apple.com/[この箇所]/アプリ名/アプリid?l=ja&ls=1&mt=8
```

もちろん、usに変更すると英語で設定した説明文やスクリーンショットが表示されます。

上記URLのカッコの箇所は、「どこの国のAppStoreを参照するのか」を表すので、アプリ以外の箇所（App Storeのメニューやその他私達に変更できない文字列）の言語も切り替わります。

URL末尾のパラメータ「l属性」に関しては「Language」つまり言語のパラメータを表すようです。

しかし、こちらで「l属性」の変更によって、どのように挙動が変化するのか試してみたのですが、Language属性を「en」や「ja」に変更しても言語が切り替わることはなく、あくまで「どの国のAppStore」を参照するのかによってiTunes Connectで設定したアプリのローカライゼーションの切り替えが行われるようでした。

更に、ブラウザによる表示ではローカライゼーションの切り替えがURLによって行われるものの、iPhoneやiPadからリンクを踏むと、どのURLを踏んでも強制的に各端末の設定言語をベースに切り替わるようです。

というわけで、基本的にスマートフォンからの操作では何も気にせずにiTune Connectの「App Storeでの表示」のリンクを利用すれば問題なさそうです。しかし、オフィシャルサイトなどからiTunes Storeへリンクさせたい場合には、PCからの利用も考えられますので、URLのカッコの箇所に注意して下さい。

iTunes Storeのアプリへのリンクに関しては、アプリのリンクを生成する「Link Maker」という公式ツールが存在しますので、こちらのツールを利用したほうが安全かもしれません。

Link MakerとURLパラメータの詳細な説明に関しては以下のURLが参考になると思います。

http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/iphone/app-store-url/

Comment: 早々にありがとうございます。助かりました<(_ _)>

Comment: @TomokoSato この回答で問題が解決したのであれば、ぜひ[回答の承認](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1735/8000)をお願いします（このコメントはそのうち削除します）